# Format and store JSON date in AngularJS variable

Tags: json, angularjs

I am using an API that returns a JSON object and has the following details:

```
id: 214609287
todolist_id: 33475634
position: 14
content: "some comment"
completed: true
created_at: "2015-10-28T14:22:58.000+05:30"
updated_at: "2015-10-28T14:31:26.000+05:30"
comments_count: 1
private: false
trashed: false
due_on: "2015-10-28"
due_at: "2015-10-28"
creator: {
    id: 7566695
    name: "some name"
    avatar_url: "a url here"
    fullsize_avatar_url: "another url here"
} - assignee: {
    id: 9329381
    type: "Person"
    name: "some name"
} - completed_at: "2015-10-28T14:31:26.000+05:30"
completer: {
    id: 9329381
    name: "another name"
}
```

I need to store the `completed_at` date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format in an AngularJS variable for comparing it with `due_on` date. I tried the following code at the latest -

```
var test = $filter('date')($scope.opendata.completed_at, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

and a few other codes too. But none worked. `$scope.opendata` contains the JSON data. The variable `test` is defined inside a function which returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
function formatDate(dateStr) {

   var date = new Date(dateStr);
   return  `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`

}

test = formatDate($scope.opendata.completed_at);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlie2002/deL62817/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Also please learn how it works. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep the date in the format provided and use a filter in your view to change the format of the date.

```
{{completed_at | date : 'yyyy mm dd'}}
```

Comment: Yes your answer is perfect if I were to just display it. But I need to store it in a variable for comparing it with the `due_on` date. Thank You for the question. I will update my question.

Comment: This looks great. Please give us the syntax or a link to learn more about it.